# Allow a flash player automatically in any web browser in raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian

I want to play an IP Camera in the chrome web browser using raspberry pi 3 automatically (when I start my raspberry pi 3) that is already I have done this.

But when I reboot the Pi 3 and when the web browser is open than my camera is not opening in a web browser because it's not allowed to play a flash player automatically. Every time it warns me that "adobe flash player is blocked because it's out of date..so, you need to update it".

But already I have installed and update a 32.0.0.207 version adobe flash player in the chrome web browser using raspberry pi 3 and also allow it in web browser !!

If any suggestion please let me inform. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) `But already I have installed and update a 32.0.0.207 version adobe flash player` can you confirm the flash player version in the browser, I believe if you're using Chromium, then the flash player is part of chromium, so, what are you "installing" (and from where!!) b) adobe flash player is end-of-life in 18 months - now would be a good time to look at alternatives

Comment: Thanks for Reply... a) I have installed it for chromium web browser at /home/pi/ location. But every time I have to give a allow permission to flash player & I want it automatically when I autostart my RPi3. b) That's why I am using firefox with shockwave player for the camera. But, here the same problem creates & one more problem is that it displays a white blank page on the web browser in Raspberry Pi 3.